# MySQL said: #1338 - Cursor declaration after handler declaration

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm on developing web project and i get some problem with migration from oracle database to mysql database. I want to create function with this code :

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS F_MANIFEST_GABUNG_SMR;

DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION F_MANIFEST_GABUNG_SMR (input_val   varchar(4000))
  RETURNS VARCHAR(4000)
BEGIN
  DECLARE return_text  VARCHAR(10000)  DEFAULT  NULL;
DECLARE not_found INT DEFAULT 0;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET not_found = 1; 
  DECLARE x CURSOR FOR SELECT DISTINCT IFNULL(SMR,'-') SMR FROM MANIFEST_EDI_SMR WHERE BL_NBR = input_val; OPEN x;
 FETCH x INTO;
 WHILE NOT_FOUND=0
 DO
    SET return_text = concat(ifnull(return_text, '') , ' ' , IFNULL(x.SMR, '')) ;
  FETCH  INTO;
  END WHILE;
  CLOSE ;
  IF char_length(return_text) > 85 THEN
       SET return_text = concat(ifnull(substr(return_text,1,85), '') , ' detail asp BL'); 
  END IF;
  RETURN return_text;
END;
//

DELIMITER ;
```

I am using phpmyadmin to store function with routine. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Please add your error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is self explanatory:you have declare the cursor after handler,need to change the order:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS F_MANIFEST_GABUNG_SMR;

DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION F_MANIFEST_GABUNG_SMR (input_val   varchar(4000))
  RETURNS VARCHAR(4000)
BEGIN
  DECLARE return_text  VARCHAR(10000)  DEFAULT  NULL;
DECLARE not_found INT DEFAULT 0;

-- Declare cursor before handler
DECLARE x CURSOR FOR SELECT DISTINCT IFNULL(SMR,'-') SMR 
 FROM MANIFEST_EDI_SMR WHERE BL_NBR = input_val; OPEN x;

-- handler need to be after cursor
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET not_found = 1; 

 FETCH x INTO;
 WHILE NOT_FOUND=0
 DO
    SET return_text = concat(ifnull(return_text, '') , ' ' , IFNULL(x.SMR, '')) ;
  FETCH  INTO;
  END WHILE;
  CLOSE ;
  IF char_length(return_text) > 85 THEN
       SET return_text = concat(ifnull(substr(return_text,1,85), '') , ' detail asp BL'); 
  END IF;
  RETURN return_text;
END;
//

DELIMITER ;
```

More details can be found at:https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cursors.html